# cq.util.eval function retuning null object when the request coming from Web server

Tags: aem

I have below function in the search.jsp. I'm using an object `abc` to get  the search and promote account details dynamically.

```
var abc=  CQ.Util.eval(spPath+'/jcr:content.json');
```

Here consider `sPath` is search and promote directory (ex: /etc/cloudservoices/search-promote/abc-search-promote)

If I print the value of `abc` in publish instance (http://publish:4503/en-US/home.html) then it's returning an object whereas it's returning `null` if I access it through the web server (http://test:80/en-US/home.html).

Can you kindly suggest what might possibly be wrong?

Comment: Check your dispatcher rules and see if the path `/etc/cloudservices` is allowed or denied. Probably it might have been denied. In case it is allowed, check if the `.json` extension is allowed or denied.

Comment: Thank you Rakhi. After allowing .json extension from dispatcher rules, it's  working from web server.